# Adding has_and_belong_to_many entity using static method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, static

I have two models :

```
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :candidates

    def self.add
        find_or_create_by(name:"management")
    end
end
```

The following execution seems to work fine :

```
>current_candidate.skills.count
=> 0
>current_candidate.skills.find_or_create_by(name:"mathematics")
=> ...
>current_candidate.skills.count
=> 1
```

But here is what happen when I use the static method `add` :

```
>current_candidate.skills.count
=> 0
>current_candidate.skills.add
=> ...
>current_candidate.skills.count
=> 0
```

The skill `management` is created, but not binded to my candidate entity.
I don't understand why the static method doesn't consider the `current_candidate`.

*PS: It works well with direct binding (like has_many and belongs_to)*

Comment: What candidate entity? You'd have to pass that in the add method and then set the property on find_or_create_by in the add method

Answer (score 0):

New answer (previous answer deleted):

Your code will not work because you have defined `add` as a class method of `Skill`. The **class** `Skill` has no relation to candidates. An **instance** of a `Skill` does have a relation to candidates.

So to fix this, I think it makes more sense to add an `add_skill` method on `Candidate` and remove the one in `Skill`.

```
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills

  def add_skill(skill_name)
    skills.find_or_create_by(name: skill_name)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
current_candidate.add_skill('a_skill')
```

As stated in my previous answer, you might want to replace the `find_or_create_by` call with the bang version `find_or_create_by!` to catch (validation) errors.

Comment: Doesn't work, no relations in he `candidates_skills` table are created.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked something important. Answer updated.